# Complicated Sql Query Logic

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem to solve in mysql. And I am using MYSQL tool. I deal with call center message logs. Say i have a table corresponding to Message_Replies. And its columns are 'id', 'responder', 'timestamp'. Responder can have two values:- 'agent', 'user'.Entries with responder = 'agent' are entries which our agent replied and entries with responder = 'user' are entries which user replied.

`Say we have a sequences of messages like this:- User, Agent, User, User, Agent, User, User, Agent, User, Agent.`

I want to get avg response time for this ticket. The ideal way is to get first message timestamp by 'user' , then first message timestamp by 'agent' nd subtract this timestamp to get the response time. Next get first entry of 'user' and next first entry of 'agent' and get their time differnce. ie if two continue replies  are from 'user' then i have to take the first reply by 'user' and get next first entry for 'agent', and get their time difference. I m not getting how to get the time diff of first reply of user and next first reply of agent.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Does each record also have a timestamp?  This sounds like a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: I would appear that your table misses (at least) one field that would enable proper focusing onto a **conversation**. I mean, your table appears to store conversations between many users and many agents (where, additionally, a single agent may have active conversations with more than one user).

Comment: This would really be clearer with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below
1. create a temp table let's say t1 and insert data into it using select query for messages where responder =user with minimum timestamp and grouping by id of message.
2. create another temp table t2, insert data into it using select query for messages where responder=agent with maximum timestamp and grouping by id of message
3. now use join and date subtraction to get response time for messages (tickets)